# Android 6.0 camera permission denied

Tags: android, android-studio, камера, permissions

Данный код отлично работает с камерой в версиях андроида ниже 6.0. Но с версией 6.0 выдаёт ошибку в использование камеры. Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

ImageView ivCamera, ivGallery, ivUpload, ivImage;

CameraPhoto cameraPhoto;
GalleryPhoto galleryPhoto;

final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 13323;
final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 22131;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    cameraPhoto = new CameraPhoto(getApplicationContext());
    galleryPhoto = new GalleryPhoto(getApplicationContext());

    ivImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    ivCamera = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivCamera);
    ivGallery = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivGallery);
    ivUpload = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivUpload);

    ivCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            try {
                startActivityForResult(cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent(), CAMERA_REQUEST);
                cameraPhoto.addToGallery();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Something Wrong while taking photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    ivGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(galleryPhoto.openGalleryIntent(), GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
            String photoPath = cameraPhoto.getPhotoPath();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Something Wrong while loading photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        else if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST){
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(uri);
            String photoPath = galleryPhoto.getPath();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Something Wrong while choosing photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

[image: Android Manifest]

[image: Android Monitor]

[image: Main Activity]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Permission denied...
```

Это не спроста. Начиная с `Android 6.0` и выше нужно обрабатывать такие `permission`, спрашивая у пользователя давать добро на использование камеры или нет.

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;

if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);//выводит диалог, где пользователю предоставляется выбор
        }else{
             //продолжаем работу или вызываем метод или класс
        }
```

Обновление ответа:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;
 ....


ivCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
  if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);//выводит диалог, где пользователю предоставляется выбор
            }else{
                try {
                startActivityForResult(cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent(), CAMERA_REQUEST);
                cameraPhoto.addToGallery();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Something Wrong while taking photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }  
        }
    });
```

Comment: Огмромное спасибо за ответ. Можете подсказать пожалуйста. В каком месте Main Activity ваш код нужно интегрировать в свой

Comment: @KimVladislav рад был помочь!:) я обновил свой ответ

Comment: Извините я кажется не правильно следую вашим указаниям. Но не удалось выполнить команду. http://i.stack.imgur.com/HjeyD.png

Comment: @KimVladislav не "this" тогда, а "MainActivity.this". Вам даже студя подсказывает... this (anonymus) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с шестой версии андроида механизм запроса разрешений изменился:
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

По-сути, надо вызывать разрешения рантайм при необходимости функцией `requestPermissions`